# How to include "compressed" parameter in curl functions in PHP?

Tags: php, libcurl, php-curl

Ineed to make a request exactly like the browser does it with CURL and PHP, when a copy as Curl (cmd) i see this headers:

```
curl "https://www.w3schools.com/js/ajax_info.txt" 
-H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors" 
-H "referer: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first" 
-H "Origin: https://www.w3schools.com" 
-H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"  
-H "dnt: 1" 
--compressed
```

I have some code but i need more options, for example the part "--compressed" i do not have idea how to include it at  request

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.w3schools.com/js/ajax_info.txt');

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;

?>
```

i can nnot see a result beacause are headers

Comment: Plop it in http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php

Answer (score 1):

You set the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` option and ask for specific encodings (compression methods) or let curl itself ask for the encodings it knows of. Unless you have special knowledge, letting curl ask for what it supports generally gets the best results.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

Note that the neat [curl-to-php service](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/) mentioned in a comment works for this but will generate the non-optimal version with a fixed set of methods. I've filed a separate [bug report](https://github.com/incarnate/curl-to-php/issues/22) on that.

This option is called [CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ACCEPT_ENCODING.html) in the underlying libcurl, as it was renamed there many years ago.